# Spring Cloud Contract - Query Parameter contracts always matches to the same contract

Tags: spring-boot, groovy, spring-boot-test, wiremock, spring-cloud-contract

I am working on spring cloud contract and have a use-case where I want the response to be BAD_REQUEST when a few query parameters are missing and OK when all the mandatory query parameter are present. In order to achieve this, I have different contracts(groovy files) to cater each of such request/responses. But when I test from the consumer(with/without query parameters) all of these match to only 1 contract whether or the query parameter is present.

Contracts listed below,

**Both the query parameters are not present**

```
Contract.make {
    description("Test to see if authorisation works")
    request {
        method 'GET'
        urlPath("/check/validate")
        headers {
            contentType('application/json')
        }
    }
    response {
        status(400)
        "body" "shouldReturnBadRequest400BothFieldsNotPresent"
        headers {
            contentType('application/json')
        }
    }
```

}

**Query parameters B is not present**

```
Contract.make {
    description("Test to see if authorisation works")
    request {
        method 'GET'
        urlPath("/check/validate") {
            queryParameters {
                parameter 'a' : value(regex(nonBlank()))
            }
    }
    headers {
        contentType('application/json')
    }
}
response {
    status(400)
    "body" "shouldReturnBadRequest400BNotPresent"
    headers {
        contentType('application/json')
    }
}
```

}

**Query Parameters are present and response is OK**

```
Contract.make {
    description("Test to see if authorisation works")
    request {
        method 'GET'
        urlPath('/check/validate') {
            queryParameters {
                parameter 'a' : equalTo("AUTHORISED")
                parameter 'b' : value(regex(nonBlank()))
            }
        }
        headers {
            contentType('application/json')
        }
    }
    response {
        status(200)
        "body" "shouldReturn200OkValidRequest"
        headers {
            contentType('application/json')
        }
    }
```

}

Questions:

1. All of my testcases match to the first case **Both the query parameters are not present** rather than matching to specifics. Please let me know what I am missing.
2. Can someone please point to the spring-cloud-contract documentation on query parameters which cater the above requirement. Found this(http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-contract/1.0.x/#_passing_optional_parameters) but I need some more information on my above requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your contracts are extending one another. Each is more concrete than the other. You have to use the `priority()` method to say which one is more concrete than the other. E.g. the least concrete should have the highest value priority - `priority(100)` . The most - `priority(1)`.

Both the query parameters are not present

```
Contract.make {
    priority(100)
    description("Test to see if authorisation works")
    request {
        method 'GET'
        urlPath("/check/validate")
        headers {
            contentType('application/json')
        }
    }
    response {
        status(400)
        "body" "shouldReturnBadRequest400BothFieldsNotPresent"
        headers {
            contentType('application/json')
        }
    }
}
```

Query parameters B is not present

```
Contract.make {
    priority(50)
    description("Test to see if authorisation works")
    request {
        method 'GET'
        urlPath("/check/validate") {
            queryParameters {
                parameter 'a' : value(regex(nonBlank()))
            }
    }
    headers {
        contentType('application/json')
    }
}
response {
    status(400)
    "body" "shouldReturnBadRequest400BNotPresent"
    headers {
        contentType('application/json')
    }
}
}
```

Query Parameters are present and response is OK

```
Contract.make {
    priority(10)
    description("Test to see if authorisation works")
    request {
        method 'GET'
        urlPath('/check/validate') {
            queryParameters {
                parameter 'a' : equalTo("AUTHORISED")
                parameter 'b' : value(regex(nonBlank()))
            }
        }
        headers {
            contentType('application/json')
        }
    }
    response {
        status(200)
        "body" "shouldReturn200OkValidRequest"
        headers {
            contentType('application/json')
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 thanks for the super quick reply  Marcin. I had explored this option to use priority, but wanted to make sure that it is the recommended way to implement for my usecase